How to disable JavaScript minification in shopware bundle all.js in dev environment?
According to Shopware's AI chat the answer is:
To stop Shopware from compressing javascript in the all.js bundle, you can add the following line to your config/packages/shopware.yaml file:
shopware:
    storefront:
        bundle:
            minify: false

I tried updating my yaml file as suggested, but ran into following error during deployment.
Unrecognized option "storefront" under "shopware". Available options are "admin_worker", "api", "auto_update", "cache", "cart", "cdn", "dal", "deployment", "feature", "filesystem", "html_sanitizer", "increment", "logger", "media", "sales_channel_context", "sitemap", "store".


what are you trying to achieve? to not have a minified version of all.js or to exclude some javascript from the bundle?

I'm trying to debug some shopware plugins in Chrome's debugger and I want to see the unminified/unchanged code during debugging which is same or closer to my source code. Doesn't shopware provide an easy way to stop transpiling and minifying scripts during development?

I am not sure that the solution provided by AI is correct.. If all, you will end up with unminified js
If you want to exclude some javascript from the bundle, maybe you need to set that specific javascript as a js plugin and import it dynamically
you can find something for that here -> https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-javascript.html#registering-an-async-plugin

That is all I want, to end up with unminified js! ;)
